# how to parse this json object -> arraylist of linkedHashMap

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

Below are the two urls which returns json response

1) https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

2) https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

When user hit the first url ,I want to see all users information with their related posts.
Note:id of users is present in posts response.

I need java code to parse this response.

Comment: for(int i =0;i<userDetails.size();i++) {
     LinkedHashMap hm = (LinkedHashMap) userDetails.get(i);  
      userId =((Integer) hm.get("id"));
    }

Comment: i have added above code to find all the user ids from the users response object,By passing this id i want to fetch the details from POSTS rest end point  response and then i have to append this response to the users response object

Comment: If you need the result written in Java then please add an appropriate tag. You could also add the code that you already have.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using Google's gson for serialization from/to json.
You can find the latest version of gson [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson)

First add this dependency to your **pom.xml**

Then, create in your implementation create a new Gson object:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
```

Lets assume that you created the **User** model and a **Users** class which encapsulates User list, what you will do is:

```
List<User> users = gson.fromJson(responseString, Users.class);
```

After this point you can convert your Users object to any data structure you desire using Java streams.

You can do the vice versa by using **toJson** method of Gson.

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem @shaleen?